# What is a best way to implement different question types(multiple choices and text-based ) in a quiz/survey application using C#, MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

I have developed an application that generates a survey based on the question types set on the database.
I have a condition that checks the question type and generates a radio button, checkbox, or textbox. I also have a loop that iterates through the question options controls by an index. I identify each control by index.

I use form collection to pass the values to the controller.

Is there a better way of doing this because the solution I have is not efficient if there is a large number of questions?

Comment: What part is inefficient? Do explain, because "a better way" is pretty much an open question with a wide range of different answers.

Comment: I am using a nested loop inside the view for the question and question options in the razor view. I generate id for the controls based on the question index.

Comment: Still unclear what the inefficient part is

Comment: I am using formCollection to pass control values to the controller. I would like to know what would be a better way of passing control values to the controller.  My question types are single choice, multiple options, and free text.

Comment: Besides the part where you identify each control by index - I would attempt to rewrite that to database ID (so the order of the form does not matter) - I think the FormCollection is one the few options you have left since your input is purely based on the contents of the database.